# Why is the logical call context not propagated across threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a weird problem with logical call contexts not propagating to threads in my application.

In this sample, the thread (created before logical call context data is set) does not pick up the new value:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dispatcher = new MessageDispatcher();

        //Logical call context data not set yet
        Console.WriteLine($"Main: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: {CallContext.LogicalGetData("myvar")}"); // Main logical call context data is not set yet = Null
        dispatcher.Broadcast("a string"); // logical call context data is still not set yet = Null

        //Logical call context data is set now
        CallContext.LogicalSetData("myvar", "Logical call context variable");
        Console.WriteLine($"Main: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: {CallContext.LogicalGetData("myvar")}"); // Main logical call context data is set = return value

        dispatcher.Broadcast("a string"); // Logical call context data is set and should return the data set above?

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public class MessageDispatcher
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _messages;
        private readonly AutoResetEvent _waitHandle;
        private bool _terminate;
        private bool _messageMonitoringActive;

        public MessageDispatcher()
        {
            _messages = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
            _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            var thread = new Thread(MonitorCollection);
            thread.Start();
        }

        public void Broadcast(string message)
        {
            _messages.Enqueue(message);
            _waitHandle.Set();
        }

        private void MonitorCollection()
        {
                _waitHandle.WaitOne();

                string message;
                while (_messages.TryDequeue(out message))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        $"{message}: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: {CallContext.LogicalGetData("myvar")}");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

For all calls made within the created thread, the call context data is not adopted from the just set context variable. Why is that?

In my application, I can't set logical call context variable at instantiation (which is done via IoC on startup (it's a WebAPI stack)), but only on each invocation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) states that

> CallContext is a specialized collection object similar to a Thread Local Storage for method calls and provides data slots that are unique to each logical thread of execution. The slots are not shared across call contexts on other logical threads. Objects can be added to the CallContext as it travels down and back up the execution code path, and examined by various objects along the path.

And also that

> All methods in CallContext are static and operate on the call context in the current Thread.

Just from reading the documentation, you'd think that this scenario just won't work. And that's true for the `SetData` and `GetData` methods; if you use `SetData` on one thread, you have to use `GetData` on the same thread to get the data back out.

There is an exception, though; `SetLogicalData` and `GetLogicalData`, which you're already using. These are designed to flow context through "logical threads", i.e. across the same thread *and* through to child threads.

The problem with your approach is that you're trying to pass data *after* the child thread has been created and started, which won't work. If you move

```
CallContext.LogicalSetData("myvar", "Logical call context variable");
```

above

```
var dispatcher = new MessageDispatcher();
```

i.e. before the thread is created and started (in the `MessageDispatcher` constructor). You'll see that you get the value out correctly.

In other words; you need to make sure all data is set before you create and start the child thread.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that was also what I noticed. However that kinda sucks for my usecase, because the messagedispatcher is constructed as a singleton at startup (in my WebAPI-stack) but the correlationid is set each time the api endpoint is invoked. From this invocation, I now need to send a message through my dispatcher (which in reality is a dispatcher that handles messages on a RabbitMQ-queue) - and in that dispatcher, I would like to get the new correlation-id from the endpoint invocation...

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating stuff here. Why are you even doing explicit threading in 2015? What are you using this correlation ID for? Why can't you pass it to the dispatcher from the controller?

Comment: Initially because the actual code, that does this, is in a nuget package from another team at my company and changes are hard to get implemented by them. But you're right, I should try to see how I can circumvent this somehow in my own solution. I'll give it a try tomorrow :) Thanks!